# RCP - How to decorate an image with another image

Tags: java, image, swt, eclipse-rcp, tableviewer

I've some column-image in a JFace `TableViewer`. Unfortunately it seems that the column-image is only allowed to be 16px wide which is to small to show two images. I've tried with a 32px image but it was compressed to a 16px x 16px image. Maybe there is some decorator which I can use to overlay two pictures automatically?

Is there any possibility to do this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "_overlap two pictures_"?

Comment: There is no limitation regarding the size of a column image. All images are resized to the first image you're returning in your `LabelProvider`

Comment: I've got a basic image as background and want to overlay a second image. Like two layers in gimp. The two images should not be  overlayed exactely but lightly shifted.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with an [CompositeImageDescriptor](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/resource/CompositeImageDescriptor.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can draw `Image`s of any size in a `TableViewer` by using [`OwnerDrawLabelProvider`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FOwnerDrawLabelProvider.html).

You will then have to paint the image yourself in the method:

```
protected void paint(Event event, Object element)
```

and define the table cell size in the method:

```
protected void measure(Event event, Object element)
```

There is a brilliant tutorial by Vogella [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html) with [example code](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html#jfacetable_styledlabelprovider).

The result looks like this:

[image]

If you want to overlay the images, just set the alpha of the `GC` to something semi-transparent with [`GC#setAlpha(int)`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/graphics/GC.html#setAlpha(int)).